# google search results extraction using java

Tags: java, google-maps-api-3

Is there a way I can get the top 10 results I get from google-search extracted.

example: if I give "pizza shop " in maps.google.com , it gives me on the right side some results is there a way I can get/extract those results

Comment: Take a look at: https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search

Answer (score 0):

**No**, You are not supposed to access the data via any other means other than the google interface.

In the Terms of Service of google states:

> 5.3 You agree not to access (or attempt to access) any of the Services by any means other than through the interface that is provided by
>   Google, unless you have been specifically allowed to do so in a
>   separate agreement with Google. You specifically agree not to access
>   (or attempt to access) any of the Services through any automated means
>   (including use of scripts or web crawlers) and shall ensure that you
>   comply with the instructions set out in any robots.txt file present on
>   the Services.

Comment: regardless of the terms of service, it is bad practice to scrape html that could change format at any time. however, it would have been more beneficial to the author if you were to describe the proper way to programmaticallyretrieve results from google - via the developer API.

Comment: As i understand, according to terms of service this is forbidden. So example to access a forbidden resource is not correct.